# бот не выдаёт роль участнику (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

выходит такая ошибка:

> author = bot.get_member(637...)
> AttributeError:
> 'Bot' object has no attribute 'get_member'

вот команда:

```
@bot.command()
async def close(ctx):
    author = bot.get_member(637...)
    guild = bot.get_guild(824...)
    role = guild.get_role(869...)

    await author.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(
        embed=discord.Embed(
            description=f"**нехороший человек закрылся**",
            color=discord.Color.red(),
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Откройте [**список методов объекта `discord.ext.commands.Bot`**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot#bot) и увидите, что никакого метода `get_member()` у вашего бота нет.

Об этом же говорится в тексте ошибки

```
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'get_member'
```

---

Чтобы получить участника сервера, воспользуйтесь функцией [**`discord.utils.get`**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=utils#discord.utils.get)

```
member = discord.utils.get(guild.members, id=637...)
```

Или через объект сервера:

```
member = guild.get_member(637...)
```

*Чтобы каждый раз не получать участника через `id`, можно передать его в качестве аргумента команды. Подробнее [**здесь**](https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/discord-py.md#%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B).*

---

А чтобы не сталкиваться подобными проблемами в будущем, рекомендую почитать [**краткое руководство по использованию документации**](https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/using_docs.md#%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-discord-py).

Comment: oшибka
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'guild' referenced before assignment

Comment: сначала получите объект сервера, а уже потом используйте его. У вас в коде же изначально нет переменной `guild`, которой вы пытаетесь воспользоваться, вы сервер получаете позже. Соответственно и использовать переменную нужно после ее инициализации